# wait & notify - printing different thread ids

Tags: java, multithreading

Sorry if it's a basic question. I am new to Threads.
I am trying to understand wait() and notify() a thread. Issue is the Thread IDs are print differently when i do wait and notify on the same class. Yes, notify is happening properly, but i am wondering why notify Thread IDs keep changing ? Please throw some light, wait and notify should be happening for same thread, isn't it ?

Wait thread:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class ThreadWait implements Runnable {

    private static ThreadWait threadWait;
    private ThreadNotify threadNotify = ThreadNotify.getInstance();

    private ThreadWait() {
    }

    public static ThreadWait getInstance() {
        if (threadWait == null) {
            threadWait = new ThreadWait();
        }

        return threadWait;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                        // method call in async.
                        threadNotify.notifyThread();
                    });


                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + "=======ThreadWait : wait========");
                    wait();

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void notifyThread() {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + "=======ThreadWait : Notified========");
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Notify thread

```
public class ThreadNotify {

    private static ThreadNotify threadNotify;
    private ThreadWait threadWait;

    private ThreadNotify(){}

    public static ThreadNotify getInstance(){
        if(threadNotify == null){
            threadNotify = new ThreadNotify();
        }

        return threadNotify;
    }

    public void notifyThread(){

        threadWait = ThreadWait.getInstance();
        fibonacci(44);
        //threadWait.notify()
        threadWait.notifyThread(); // want to print threadIDs, so created this method.
    }

    private int fibonacci(int n) {
        if (n <= 1)
            return n;
        else
            return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }

}
```

Main Thread:

```
public class MainThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadWait wait = ThreadWait.getInstance();

        Thread th = new Thread(wait);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

output:

```
12=======ThreadWait : wait========
14=======ThreadWait : Notified========
12=======ThreadWait : wait========
15=======ThreadWait : Notified========
12=======ThreadWait : wait========
16=======ThreadWait : Notified========
12=======ThreadWait : wait========
17=======ThreadWait : Notified========
12=======ThreadWait : wait========
18=======ThreadWait : Notified========
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I'm not understanding the question. What are you expecting and what output is unexpected?

Comment: if you see the output at the bottom of the post, 12 is the thread-id i get before i tried to wait(), 14,15,16,17,18 are different thread-ids when i tried to notify, i am wondering, why notify is printing different thread-ids, it should be same thread-id, i.e, 12. As wait and notify() happening on same thread ? Sorry if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: But you are aware of the fact that you are using `CompletableFuture` to do the method call async, right? (*hint:* `Thread.currentThread().getId()`)

Comment: When you call wait, it will stop the execution of a thread. So calling noitify has to come from a different thread. You're confounding the issue a bit by using your Thread as the Object that wait/notify is being called on.

Answer (score 0):

if you see your code in the main class `ThreadWait wait = ThreadWait.getInstance();` you are creating an instance and giving it to wait thread. Which uses a singleton pattern to create an instance. But for notify you are using  `CompletableFuture` which creates a separate thread

Comment: CompletableFuture creates a separate thread, this make sense, any suggestion how can call notifyThread() asynchronously without using CompletableFuture , so that i can wait until it is notified ?

Comment: @Molay So here is the code behind `CompletableFuture` which will help to understand. `public static CompletableFuture<Void> runAsync(Runnable runnable) {
        if (runnable == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        CompletableFuture<Void> f = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
        execAsync(ForkJoinPool.commonPool(), new AsyncRun(runnable, f));
        return f;
    }` You can check here http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java

Comment: @Molay if you see after a wait , notified is called in between which you have run in a loop for 5 times. So every time 1 wait is called after that notify thread is called. If you want more understanding then you need to debug the code and see how this is executing